# Calling a function with user defined type parameters (Oracle ODP.NET)

Tags: oracle, function, object, odp.net

I'm using a function :

```
fu_has_permissions(udt_person('johny','superman'),'fly_away')
```

udt_person is a user defined type :

```
create or replace TYPE udt_person AS OBJECT 
(name VARCHAR2(3), 
id VARCHAR2(18));
```

I want to use bind variables whan calling this function, but i'm not really sure what am i doing wrong ... Here's the code :

```
......
OracleParameter udtPersParam = new OracleParameter();
udtPersParam.ParameterName = ":pUdtPers";
udtPersParam.UdtTypeName = "UDT_PERS";
string[] paramValues = { name, id };
udtPersParam.Value = paramValues;
OracleParameter pAction = new OracleParameter(":pAction", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 255);
pAction.Value = action;

parameters.Add(udtPartParam);
parameters.Add(pAction);

try
{
_loginOdr = DBFacade.ExecuteSelectQuery("select fu_has_permissions(:pUdtPart, :pAction) from dual", parameters);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get? Is it a typo that `UdtTypeName` doesn't match the Oracle type name?

Comment: "Value does not fall within the expected range.", at line udtPersParam.Value = paramValues;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the udt type must be a class that implements 
 IOracleCustomType
and/or  IOracleCustomTypeFactory,   IOracleArrayTypeFactory

unfortuntately you cannot just create a string array and pass it in

look in the odp.net samples that come with the odp installation
%ora_home%\client_1\odp.net\samples\4\UDT

also check out these links for samples and walkthroughs
http://developergeeks.com/article/35/working-with-user-defined-type-oracle-udt-and-custom-type-using-odp-net-11g
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ORACLE_UDT.aspx
and
http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/udt/udt_otn.htm

Comment: The path to the samples was different in my case of 11.2:
%ora_home%\product\11.2.0\client_1_x86\ODACsamples\odp.net\4\UDT

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about ODP.Net really, but the error suggests that it doesn't like you trying to use a string array as the value for an Oracle parameter. Which doesn't sound unreasonable.

A quick google of 'odp.net object varchar2' gave [this OTN forum post](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=372381) as the first result; it includes an example of using an object about half-way down, including converting to and from Oracle object types.

Answer (score 1):

if I were you I'd have a look at the ODP add-in to Visual Studio. With this you can connect to your database, select a UDT on the database, and "Generate Custom Class" to get a .net class you can use.

Look inside the class and you'll see what Harrison means. Pay particular attention to the OracleObjectMappingAttributes on top of the properties, and the overrides of To/FromCustomObject.

When you construct your OracleCommand, the OracleParameter.Value needs to be a class of this type.

That should get you started at a high level. A word of warning, though. The code generated by ODP is ugly to say the least - we're on the point of ditching all ODP-generated classes in our own scenario. But you'll need to understand what things like IOracleCustomType, IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleArrayTypeFactory, INullable are before you'll be in a position to do this.

Incidentally since your specific question surrounds arrays, you might want to look at Oracle NTYPEs here, rather than TYPEs.