# Is it possible to pass objects to PL SQL package procedure as parameters?

Tags: oracle, post, plsql

Let's take an example from .NET MVC where it is possible to define `ActionResult` with a parameter that is custom object or even an array of such objects:

Method:

```
public ActionResult Blah(Person[] people) {
  // ...
}
```

and corresponding HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="people[0].FirstName" value="George" />
<input type="text" name="people[0].LastName" value="Washington" />
<input type="text" name="people[1].FirstName" value="Abraham" />
<input type="text" name="people[1].LastName" value="Lincoln" />
<input type="text" name="people[3].FirstName" value="Thomas" />
<input type="text" name="people[3].LastName" value="Jefferson" />
```

Example taken from this [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

I want to know if it is possible to do something similar in PL SQL, like:

```
PROCEDURE blah(param1 IN Person_type)
IS
BEGIN
  -- do whatever y like
END;
```

where person_type defines object, record or similar complex structure.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_parsed_name as object (
name_prefix varchar2(50),
name_first varchar2(50),
name_middle varchar2(50),
name_last varchar2(100),
name_suffix varchar2(50)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_PARSED_NAME_ARY as table of t_parsed_name;

create or replace procedure test_parsed_names(i_parsed_name_ary in t_parsed_name_ary) as
    idx pls_integer;
begin
    idx := i_parsed_name_ary.first;
    loop
        exit when idx is null;
        dbms_output.put_line('First name: ' || i_parsed_name_ary(idx).name_first || ', Last name: ' || i_parsed_name_ary(idx).name_last);
        idx := i_parsed_name_ary.next(idx);
    end loop;
end;

----------------------------------------
-- example using above procedure
declare
    l_parsed_name t_parsed_name;
    l_parsed_name_ary t_parsed_name_ary;
begin
  l_parsed_name_ary := t_parsed_name_ary();
  l_parsed_name_ary.extend(3);

  -- create some parsed names and add to array
  l_parsed_name := t_parsed_name('Mr','Joe','T','Blow','Jr');
  l_parsed_name_ary(1) := l_parsed_name;
  l_parsed_name := t_parsed_name('Mrs','Jane','','Doe','');
  l_parsed_name_ary(2) := l_parsed_name;
  l_parsed_name := t_parsed_name('','Betty','','Boop','');
  l_parsed_name_ary(3) := l_parsed_name;

  -- test the array (call procedure with object type array parameter)
  test_parsed_names(l_parsed_name_ary);
end;
```

Comment: How does the corresponding HTML looks?

Comment: When you have some input field in HTML form, let's say `<form method="post" action="/test_package.save"><input type="text" name="person_name" maxlength="200"/>...</form>`, it is possible to receive in the _save_ procedure the value of input field 'person_name' like this: `PROCEDURE save (person_name IN varchar2, position IN varchar2) IS BEGIN --code goes here; END;`. I am wondering if it is possible to somehow post values from HTML form to the object like the one You wrote. I hope, I made it clear.

Comment: @ULazdins so your question is really how to parse HTML from pl/sql?  If you wanted to parse XML, no problem.  Its a bit odd (imo) to have your procedure accept html text.  Usually accepting get/post is done in the app layer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to PL SQL and I'm coming from .NET (MVC). I think I forgot to mention that this code is running on Web server and returns a Web page. Anyway, thanks, I don't want to bother you with questions anymore because I have trouble myself understanding the environment I'm working with and therefore I cannot ask the right question.

Comment: Yeah, what I just fond out, we use Apache web server with mod_plsql

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may, but you will need to use ODP and Oracle's UDTs (User Defined Type).  Not 100% sure how to map these to the MVC bit but you may pass object types to/from .net to Oracle.

Check out these links:
[Calling a function with user defined type parameters (Oracle ODP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162364/calling-a-function-with-user-defined-type-parameters-oracle-odp-net/4218292#4218292)
(with specific attention to this walkthrough http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/udt/udt_otn.htm )

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E15167_01/featUDTs.htm

it will probably take some fine-tuning on your part to get everything to sync, but it is possible.

Comment: possible but painful. A better question would be what is gained by using object types: efficiency, less code?

Comment: I actually did some testing on using objects in the past in relation to efficiency.  on a one row-by-row basis, there is no efficiency gain.  however, once you start increasing the bandwidth and doing > 5 records (sending in collections and doing bulk binds and such) the UDT way was significantly faster for CRUDS. about 3 was break even, and anything over 3 operations you gained incremental performance.  However, if you aren't doing tens of thousands of operations you probably won't realize any efficiency gains compared to the additional coding necessary (maintenance and such).

Comment: I'm sorry if I made my question sound wrong. The result has no connection to .NET, I used it only as an illustration.

The goal is to receive multiple HTML fields from POST into one variable

I'll now take a look at the answer to figur out if it works for me.

Comment: @kevinsky my goal is to minimize code and make it more fleksible to changes. If the attributes of the object Person are changed, I am expecting this change to influence rest of the code as less as possible

Comment: @ULazdins I believe that UDTs can do exactly what you like. there is a learning curve but I really like them