# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: **element has both 'type' attribute and subtype

Tags: php, oracle, web-services

I am trying to call oracle consuming web service in php code igniter. In my oracle package, there is procedure. In which, I passed 2 parameters. 1st is number type and 2nd is Nested table. When i try to execute it, it gives me error like,

```
 "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: **element has both
  'type' attribute and subtype** in 
   /opt/lampp/htdocs/supplier_R/application/models/split_model.php:294 thrown in
   /opt/lampp/htdocs/supplier_R/application/models/split_model.php on line 294"
```

**Procedure :** 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ORACLE_PKG_R AUTHID CURRENT_USER AS

TYPE POSPLIT IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

FUNCTION ACCEPTANCE(HEADER_ID IN VARCHAR2,P_NOTE IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER;

PROCEDURE REQUEST_CHANGE(HEADER_ID IN NUMBER,P_POSP IN POSPLIT);

END ORACLE_PKG_R;

**PHP :**
**$a**=$_POST['HEADER_ID'];
**$array1**=array('Romit','22','33','44','66','02-28-2014');
**$headerbody** = array('Responsibility' => 'APPLICATION_DEVELOPER','RespApplication' => 'FND',
                    'SecurityGroup'=>'STANDARD','NLSLanguage'=>'AMERICAN',
                     'Org_Id'=>null);

**$wsdl_demo** = 'http://***/SOAProvider/plsql/proc_call/?wsdl';
**$webservice** = new WSSoapClient($wsdl_demo);
$webservice->__setUsernameToken("sysadmin", "admin@123","PasswordText"); 
try
{
    $result = $webservice-> REQUEST_CHANGE($a,$array1);
}
catch (SOAPFault $f) 
{
ECHO 'ERROR '. $f;
}

what can i do now? anyone please help me...

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this error come ? Bcoz Problem occured here when soapclient statement is executed "$webservice = new WSSoapClient($wsdl_demo);".  It works perfectly in SOAPUI test Software. PLease tell me how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have used object for your own data collection

Please refer the below link for the solution

[Is it possible to pass objects to PL SQL package procedure as parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177025/is-it-possible-to-pass-objects-to-pl-sql-package-procedure-as-parameters)

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm