# Oracle 11g - Add query results to SYS_REFCURSOR in a LOOP

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Currently, I'm working on creating a stored procedure that I can pass a list of strings to from my C# application using a `DataReader`. So part of it is also properly declaring that Associative Array so the stored procedure can accept the data.

Here is what I currently have (I'm not too concerned about the C# side of things at the moment):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PACKAGE_01
AS
    TYPE t_string_list is table of VARCHAR2(4000) index by pls_integer;

    PROCEDURE SP_TEST_01(in_list IN t_string_list, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);

END TEST_PACKAGE_01;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PACKAGE_01
AS
    PROCEDURE SP_TEST_01(in_list IN t_string_list, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS

    BEGIN
        OPEN out_cursor;
        FORALL indx IN 1..in_list.COUNT
            -- I have tried numerous different things here with no success, this is just what I have in my latest iteration
            INSERT INTO out_cursor Values (SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_COLUMN = in_list(indx));
        CLOSE out_cursor;

    END SP_TEST_01;
END TEST_PACKAGE_01;
```

Within the body of the procedure, I managed to get it to return a SYS_REFCURSOR just fine, albeit just a test without any input. Something kind of like:

```
OPEN out_cursor FOR
    SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

I can't use a simple `IN` statement for the query against SOME_TABLE since `in_list` can potentially contain thousands of records. Ideally, I'd like to populate out_cursor with one statement, instead of performing a loop.

Cursors are pretty new territory for me, so maybe it isn't possible to do what I'm thinking with them, but I haven't seen anything to the contrary.

Comment: You can't use a PL/SQL table from SQL (in 11g, things improve a bit in 12c); which is what you're attempting to do here. And you can't insert into a cursor. Are you able to create a schema-level type instead?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I'm not really familiar with creating types either though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 11g you can't access the PL/SQL table type from SQL, even if that SQL is within a PL/SQL block. You can create a schema-level type instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_string_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)
/
```

Then your package becomes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST_PACKAGE_01
AS
    PROCEDURE SP_TEST_01(in_list IN t_string_list, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END TEST_PACKAGE_01;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PACKAGE_01
AS
    PROCEDURE SP_TEST_01(in_list IN t_string_list, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
    BEGIN
        OPEN out_cursor FOR
            SELECT *
            FROM SOME_TABLE
            WHERE SOME_COLUMN IN (
              SELECT * FROM TABLE(in_list)
            );
    END SP_TEST_01;
END TEST_PACKAGE_01;
/
```

or with a join instead of `IN`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST_PACKAGE_01
AS
    PROCEDURE SP_TEST_01(in_list IN t_string_list, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS
    BEGIN
        OPEN out_cursor FOR
            SELECT st.*
            FROM TABLE(in_list) t
            JOIN SOME_TABLE st ON st.SOME_COLUMN = t.COLUMN_VALUE;
    END SP_TEST_01;
END TEST_PACKAGE_01;
/
```

The [`TABLE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2065746) is a [table collection expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2104990).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=acf12141f9ba3fa0ff6c02b1ed7660a8) with made-up table and anonymous block to test.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic I suppose, but are you familiar at all with making `parameters` in ODP.Net (specifically C#, but I can read VB.Net just fine)?

Comment: Not really, but [this might give you pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4162364/266304), or other questions have probably been asked about it.